# Не изменяется размер Frame

Tags: java

По нажатию на кнопки в подменю с определенным размером окна должен установится данный размер окна,но этого не происходит. Не могу понять почему.

```java
public class MyMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;

    public MyMenu() {
        super("Мое меню"); 
        setBounds(0,0,700,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(159,194,64));
        //setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JMenuBar ceo = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Вид");
        JMenu item = new JMenu("Размер окна");

        JMenuItem submenu = new JMenuItem("Выбрать размер окна");

        JCheckBoxMenuItem item1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("  640 x 480");

        JCheckBoxMenuItem item2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("  800 x 600");
        JCheckBoxMenuItem item3 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("1024 x 768");
        item.add(submenu);
        menu.add(item);
        item.addSeparator();
        item.add(item1);
        item.add(item2);
        item.add(item3);

        ceo.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(ceo);
        item1.addActionListener(this);        
    }

    public MyMenu(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if(s.equals("640 x 480")) 
              frame.getContentPane().setBounds(0,0,640,480);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы ожадаете, что должно сработать условие `if(s.equals("640 x 480"))`? Что выводится в `System.out.println(e.getActionCommand())`? Учитываете ли вы, что у вас в item1 лишние пробелы  (`"   640 x 480"`)?

Comment: я в переменную "s" занес "e.getActionCommand() " что бы меньше прописывать кода на каждый чек бокс.

Comment: урааа сделал спасибо большое .

Comment: пожалуйста:) но вообще, для меня совершенно не очевидно, что `actionCommand` -- это расширение окна. Я думаю, вам нужен рефакторинг кода. Команда -- это команда, а расширение окна -- это расширение окна.

Comment: Посмотрите еще ответ Константина, и придумайте нормальные названия полям (не `item1`, `item2`). Иначе другим людям (да и вам самим через неделю) будет сложно понять ваш код. Помните, что программист гораздо чаще читает код, нежели пишет его, и хорошие названия полей почти всегда оправдывают время на придумывание названия.

Comment: "public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if(s.equals("640 x 480"))setBounds(0,0,640,480);
        if(s.equals("800 x 600"))setBounds(0,0,800,600);
        if (s.equals("1024 x 768"))setBounds(0,0,1024,768);
        i
       
      } "             прописал вот такой код , но работает только первый оператор .

Comment: извиняюсь,пришлось срочно уйти , решил свою задачку вот так

Comment: "public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
       String s = e.getActionCommand();
       if(s.equals("640x480")) setBounds(700,300,640,480);
       if(s.equals("800x600")) setBounds(600,250,800,600);
       if(s.equals("1024x768")) setBounds(400,200,1024,768);
       
    } "

Comment: Все работает хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вы пытаетесь получить значение нажатого пункта меню. Скорее всего у Вас не срабатывает условие. Предлагаю заменить

```
String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if(s.equals("640 x 480"))frame.getContentPane().setBounds(0,0,640,480);
```

на

```
if (e.getSourse == item1){
frame.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
else if(...){...}
}
```

но тогда придется объявить `item1` за классом, как поле:

```
private JCheckBoxMenuItem item1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("  640 x 480");
//...
public class MyMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

задавайте фрэйму минимальный и максимальный размер:

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(640,480)
frame.setMinimumSize( dimension );
frame.setMaximumSize( dimension );
```

если минимальный размер не задан, размер окна берется по размеру содержимого.